# Push code to SVN and GIT

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have a project that I want to push to GitHub *and* our internal SVN server. I have seen many references to using git-svn, but that appears to be using git commands to push to SVN and only to one server. I want to push the changes to our internal SVN server *and* to GitHub. Is this possible? How would I set it up considering that the project is currently setup with GitHub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `.gitignore` and `.git` to `svn:ignore` and `.svn` to `.gitignore`. I can commit changes to a svn repository and the same project to a GitHub repository.

Answer (score 1):

You can push `git-svn` repository to github as well, just make sure you push it *after* pushing to `svn`, because `git-svn` will modify history (it adds svn revisions to the commit messages).

But why would you do that, anyway?

Comment: Internal source versions vs. external

Comment: We just haven't decided on a direction for that yet.

Comment: I agree, you need two commands: first `git svn dcommit` then `git push` maybe you can setup a hook to automatically push after dcommit but in any case it'll be a HELL to keep both repos in sync.

Comment: Yes, @Samus_, though this scenario is possible, I'd recommend against it unless absolutely unaviodable. If you haven't decided, you better don't go this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [SubGit](http://subgit.com) into your internal SVN server. It will create a linked Git repository that is kept in sync with the SVN repository. You may consider it as Git interface to your SVN repository.

So now you can clone this Git repository, work with it and push it back to the internal repository and to GitHub.